# Two Equations and Two Unknowns

Tags: exponential-function, systems-of-equations

$$\frac { - \left( 2 e ^ { h + l } \left( 2 ( - c + l - 1 ) e ^ { h + l + l } + ( n - 2 ) ( - c + l - 1 ) e ^ { h + l } + n ( - c + l - 1 ) e ^ { l + q + l } - 2 e ^ { h + l } \right) \right) } { \left( 2 e ^ { h + l + l } + 2 e ^ { h + l } + ( n - 2 ) e ^ { h + l } + n e ^ { d + q + l } \right) ^ { 2 } } = 0$$

and

$$\frac { \left( 2 e ^ { h + l + q } \left( 2 ( c - h + 1 ) e ^ { h + l + h } + n ( c - h + 1 ) e ^ { h + h } - ( n - 2 ) ( - c + h - 1 ) e ^ { l + q + h } + 2 e ^ { + l + q } \right) \right) } { \left( 2 e ^ { h + l + q } + 2 e ^ { h + l + h } + n e ^ { h + l } + ( n - 2 ) e ^ { l + q + h } \right) ^ { 2 } } = 0$$

The parameters are $q , n ,$ and the variables are $h$ and $l$. All parameters and variables
are strictly positive.
I am looking for a set of conditions on the parameters, such that:

1. $h , l > c$
2. $n > 2$
3. $q - h > - l$
4. Optional $: h > l$ (I have a feeling that this condition should hold)

**Question**

All I want is a hint as to how to proceed -- I'm not asking for an answer, just a hint.

Comment: The first thing I would do is multiply both sides of each equation by the denominator on the left.

Comment: Note that $\frac ab=0 \implies a=0\cdot b \implies a=0$